# Entity framework migration - add new column with a value for existing entries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have an application with Entity Framework Code First.

In a table, I have to add a column. So I added it in the model and created a Migration.

But during the migration, I would like to update the existing entries and add a value for this new column. This value has to be taken from the database (a constant field in my "Configuration" table).

But the default value should only be applied for existing entries, not for the next.

How can I do it from my Migration class ?

My current migration class :

```
public override void Up()
{
    var theDefaultValue = MyConstants.MyConstantParameterFromDatabase;
    AddColumn("MySchema.MyTable", "MyNewColumn", c => c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2));
}
```

Edit : still looking for a solution to update all existing entries (with 0 value) but only after this migration...

Comment: The column should have a default (e.g. 0.0) because it's not nullable, but you should modify existing records in the `Seed` method.

Comment: Thx. So, in the Seed method, I do a foreach on the DbSet I need and assign a value if the current value is 0 for example ?

Comment: Yes,  that's the idea.

Answer (score 28):

You simply have to modify the `Up()` method, and include in it a SQL statement to set the column value in the existing rows. This will only be executed when the database is updated, and the update involves this particular Migration. Thus only the already existing rows will be updated when the `Update-Database` is invoked.

Add code like this after the `AddColumn` command, so that the column is already available in the table when the SQL statement runs:

```
Sql("UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET Column = (SELECT val FROM config)");
```

*NOTE: `(SELECT val FROM config)` is pseudocode that you must replace with a query that returns the desired value*

Comment: Since he has the value in a variable `theDefaultValue` in his migration, he can use it like this: `Sql(@"UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET MyNewColumn = " + theDefaultValue + ";")`

Comment: @AndyRaddatz Please, before changing an answer (I mean do more than correcting typos or changing the wording), re-read the question: --This value has to be taken from the database (a constant field in my "Configuration" table).--

Comment: Why is microsoft making things harder to acquire by implementing their new tool?  Certainly does not look like an improvement to me by using their tool!

Comment: @JennaLeaf I don't understand the comment. No one is forcing you to use any tool. If you want to do this in any other way (create SQL scripts, changes your ORM by hand or use direct queries with ADO.NET), you can. I think this tool makes things easier. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to copy a value from an existing column and inset to the newly introduced column in my `Postgresql` database, while running the `update-database`. So I edited the `Up` function in the `Migration` class.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder) {
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn < string > (
    name: "FileName", table: "FavoriteFiles", nullable: false, defaultValue: "");
    migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE \"FavoriteFiles\" SET \"FileName\" = SPLIT_PART(\"FilePath\", '/', 7) WHERE \"FilePath\" IS NOT NULL;");
}
```

Then I ran `Update-Database`. Hope it helps.